# How to show and hide charts using dropdown or selection box in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: excel, ms-office, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, excel-charts

I am creating a graphical report in LibreOffice Calc. In that, I have 2 different charts first is 'Customer Conversion Rate' chart and the second is 'Customer Churn Chart'.

Show in Screenshot.
[image]

I used a dropdown list from Data-> Validity In that I added above two chart name as a list item.

I want to do like when I click on 'Customer Conversion Rate' Chart it shows only that chart and other chart is hide and vise Versa.

If it is possible from filter option then it will also useful for me.

Comment: You might want to add `#excel-chart` to the tags of your post. The answer is YES in `excel` but I am not sure about `libreoffice`. The logic is to use linked pictures of your charts say Chart1, Chart2, etc. and a blank picture of the same size as your chart. When you use drop down list to select Chart1 to show the linked picture of Chart1 while show blank picture for all other charts. You may want to google **dynamically switching picture in Excel** and give it a go. If you encounter any problem you can update your post and someone if not me can help you accordingly.

Comment: Hi @Terry W , Thanks for the suggestion. I will try to use this alternate solution of linked pictures. But first I want to try with the chart because they are showing a live report.